# Beacon: Getting started with physical web

Tags: iot

I am interested in **physical web** (beacon).

How do I start my work regarding this technology?

Comment: These sort of questions really bum me out.  There is a website called Google.com.  Have you tried using it for research?  Please at least try on your own before asking others.  I am going to close this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are few tutorials, Please go through the following links: https://google.github.io/physical-web/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a minute to look at [answer]. In particular, link-only answers are discouraged here since the external website may change, instead, summarize and quote the relevant information in your answer.